# Can a rental lease with landlord as strong ties of home country?

Tags: schengen

Currently based in Ireland with stamp 4 but hold visa required passport. Had successful travel to different schengen country before based still student time but last one nearly 4yrs ago.
Now I want to visit my family in Spain  but currently unemployed I'm planning to look for a new one after the trip.
So what should I proof the strong tie is lease enough? Or proof that stamp 4 condition that I can't leave more than 6weeks?

Comment: I don't see how a rental agreement proves you will return, you could just walk away from it and stop paying.

Comment: A stronger case would be to get a job first, that begins after your scheduled return date.

Comment: You might use the "Search on Travel" box at the top of the page, and look for previous questions and answers that deal with "Home ties" or "Ties to Home Country." There are a lot.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship? When is your Stamp4 valid until/due for renewal?

Comment: stamp until 2024 and i only want to go on december this year